# Property of absolute value in the real numbers

Tags: absolute-value, real-numbers, ordered-fields

To prove that $ \lvert a-b \rvert \le c-d $ for $ a,b,c,d $ in the real numbers, what needs to be shown?

Is the fact that $a-b\le c-d$ enough? Or is there something more that needs to be shown?

Comment: What if $a=c=d=0$ and $b=1$? $a-b=-1\le0=c-d$, but $|a-b|=1\not\le 0$.

Comment: You really should always recall the definition of *absolute value* in instances such as these. For example, you have
$$
|a-b| = 
\begin{cases}
a-b & \text{if } a-b\geq 0,\\
-(a-b) & \text{if } a-b < 0.
\end{cases}
$$
Thus, "what needs to be shown" is...

Comment: More relevant here is the definition: $\enspace\lvert a-b\rvert=\max(a-b,b-a)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a - b \le c - d$ is not enough.

For example, $a = b = -999, c = d = 1$.

What you need to show is that $a - b \le c - d$ and $b - a \le c - d$. You need both.

Comment: Okay thank you, that would show that $\lvert a-b \rvert \le c-d$?

Comment: Yes. If $a - b \le 0$, then $|a - b| = b - a$.